# How to fix this error: attempt to index a number value in Lua Script

Tags: function, if-statement, error-handling, lua

I'm learning Lua but I got this error attempt to index a number value when compiler reach this piece of code

```
if a() == -1 then
    return code
end
```

Console Error

[image: 1]

i tried to change the type of return from number to boolean but i got the same error

Boolean console error

[image: 2]

```
function a()
    local message = developer:historicalMessage(22)
    if message == nil or message[1] == nil then return nil end
    message = message[1]
    if message.subs == 0 then
        global:printMessage("Here !")
        return -1
    end
end

function Notif()
    if a() == -1 then
        return code
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told us the line, but there are only a few indexing operations:

- `developer:historicalMessage(...)` and `global:printMessage(...)` are presumably not the cause. If `developer` and `global` were numbers, they could be however. That seems unlikely to me as they are being used as "method tables" though (probably with metatables).
- `message.subs` might be indexing the number `message` if `developer:historicalMessage(22)[1]` is a number.

Comment: Hey @LMD
thank you for the quick response
What line you are talking about so i can add it

Comment: @AmineFARHAT the line the error message shows